# read texture filename from fbx with fbx sdk c++

Tags: c++, textures, filenames, fbx

I got stuck while trying to get information out of a fbx file using the fbx sdk. I created a fbx model in maya with a texture on it. all i want to do is find the full filename to the used texture in code...

here is some code:

```
void Model::GetFbxInfo(FbxNode* Node)
{
int numKids = Node->GetChildCount();
FbxNode* childNode = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numKids; i++)
{
    childNode = Node->GetChild(i);
    FbxMesh* mesh = childNode->GetMesh();

    if (mesh != NULL)
    {
        // get vertices, indices, uv, etc
        // some more code...
        // get vertices, indices, uv, etc

        //================= Texture ========================================

        int materialCount = childNode->GetSrcObjectCount<FbxSurfaceMaterial>();

        for (int index = 0; index < materialCount; index++)
        {
            FbxSurfaceMaterial* material = (FbxSurfaceMaterial*)childNode->GetSrcObject<FbxSurfaceMaterial>(index);

            if (material != NULL)
            {
                LOG(INFO) << "\nmaterial: " << material->GetName() << std::endl;
                // This only gets the material of type sDiffuse, you probably need to traverse all Standard Material Property by its name to get all possible textures.
                FbxProperty prop = material->FindProperty(FbxSurfaceMaterial::sDiffuse);

                // Check if it's layeredtextures
                int layeredTextureCount = prop.GetSrcObjectCount<FbxLayeredTexture>();

                if (layeredTextureCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < layeredTextureCount; j++)
                    {
                        FbxLayeredTexture* layered_texture = FbxCast<FbxLayeredTexture>(prop.GetSrcObject<FbxLayeredTexture>(j));
                        int lcount = layered_texture->GetSrcObjectCount<FbxTexture>();

                        for (int k = 0; k < lcount; k++)
                        {
                            FbxTexture* texture = FbxCast<FbxTexture>(layered_texture->GetSrcObject<FbxTexture>(k));
                            // Then, you can get all the properties of the texture, include its name
                            const char* textureName = texture->GetName();
                            LOG(INFO) << textureName;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Directly get textures
                    int textureCount = prop.GetSrcObjectCount<FbxTexture>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < textureCount; j++)
                    {
                        FbxTexture* texture = FbxCast<FbxTexture>(prop.GetSrcObject<FbxTexture>(j));
                        // Then, you can get all the properties of the texture, include its name
                        const char* textureName = texture->GetName();
                        LOG(INFO) << textureName;

                        FbxProperty p = texture->RootProperty.Find("Filename");
                        LOG(INFO) << p.Get<FbxString>() << std::endl;


                        HRESULT hr;
                        D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile(Game::GetInstance()->GetRenderer()->GetDevice(), textureName, 0, 0, &m_texture, &hr);
                        if(FAILED(hr))
                        {
                            std::string message;
                            message.append("Load Texture: ");
                            message.append(texture->GetName());
                            message.append(" failed");
                            SHOWMESSAGEBOX(hr, message.c_str());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this->GetFbxInfo(childNode);
    }
}
```

}

it's a diffuse nonlayered texture ... so the else branch is important... textureCount is 1 - so the texture is found but filename and texture getname only return "file1"

here is a piece of data from the ascii-fbx file that I am loading

```
Video: 900530112, "Video::file1", "Clip" {
    Type: "Clip"
    Properties70:  {
        P: "Path", "KString", "XRefUrl", "", "D:/Dropbox/Projects/MyModel/MyTexture.jpg"
    }
    UseMipMap: 0
    Filename: "D:/Dropbox/Projects/MyModel/MyTexture.jpg"
    RelativeFilename: "MyTexture.jpg"
}
Texture: 785759328, "Texture::file1", "" {
    Type: "TextureVideoClip"
    Version: 202
    TextureName: "Texture::file1"
    Properties70:  {
        P: "CurrentTextureBlendMode", "enum", "", "",0
        P: "UVSet", "KString", "", "", "map1"
        P: "UseMaterial", "bool", "", "",1
    }
    Media: "Video::file1"
    FileName: "D:/Dropbox/Projects/MyModel/MyTexture.jpg"
    RelativeFilename: "MyTexture.jpg"
    ModelUVTranslation: 0,0
    ModelUVScaling: 1,1
    Texture_Alpha_Source: "None"
    Cropping: 0,0,0,0
}
```

can anyone help me understanding what I am doing wrong?

thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gotta cast your fbxtexture to fbxfiletexture ... then getfilename